# Best approach to vertical positioning of elements based on a design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, css-grid

I have a simple splash screen for a mobile app with ~6 elements. I'm using bootstrap and for my initial approach I've placed each element in its own row container.

As you can see in the design the items are positioned vertically with irregular distances between them.

I'm unsure what the best approach is to achieve a vertical alignment identical to my design. Is my use of 1 row container per item ideal?

initial HTML structure (JSX).

```
<div className='container-fluid vh-100 align-items-center text-center p-0'>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <Logo />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <h1>Welcome to SAIDONG</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <p>Cash back on purchases at your favorite places</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <SplashImage />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='row justify-content-center'>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <p>Don't have an account? <a href=''>Sign Up</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <FooterImage
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0
    }}
  />
</div>
```

the design:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use of a `.row` for each `.col-12` in this case is redundant since all of the elements inside it occupies whole available horizontal space. The same result can be archived by using only one `.row`:

```html
<div className='container-fluid vh-100 align-items-center text-center p-0'>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <Logo />
    </div>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <h1>Welcome to SAIDONG</h1>
    </div>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <p>Cash back on purchases at your favorite places</p>
    </div>
    <div className='col-12'>
      <SplashImage />
    </div>
    <div className='col-12 justify-content-center'>
      <p>Don't have an account? <a href=''>Sign Up</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <FooterImage
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0
    }}
  />
</div>
```

To achieve vertical offset between each block, you can add specific classes on each block (since all of them looks diferent from screenshot) and define appropriate margin (top or bottom). For instance:

```html
<div className='container-fluid vh-100 align-items-center text-center p-0'>
  <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-12 logo-section'>
      <Logo />
    </div>

<!-- ... -->
```

```css
.logo-section {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best solution would be to use CSS flexbox method.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#align-content

The `align-content` property should do the trick for you. Here's a link to it for tailwind: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-content

Comment: How about achieving the spacing of each element vertically similar to the design? The elements are irregularly positioned

Comment: You can try to combine `align-content:space-between` with manually setting the  margin-top|margin-bottom on the elements that are irregularly positioned.